# SQLite.net c# connection string error

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, connection, uri

This may be related to trying to connect to a URI location on a server, and so I read I needed the "SQLiteConnection(..., true)" parameter in the SQLiteConnection.  Can anyone indicate why this method or connection string is wrong?  I've tried several variations...

```
oConnection = new System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + sFileName + "; Version=3; foreign keys=true;", true);
```

sFileName is in the format "\\aServer\projects\Database.xxxx".

Comment: sFIleName should be complete path to your db file. ("C:\DataBases\db.sqlite).

Comment: Yes, it is.  Is there an issue because it's a server path?

Comment: Ary you try connect inside server or remote?

Comment: It is a server in my company that I have read and write access to.  I've programmatically created the database, and I had previous test cases of reading and writing to the database.  But since maybe when the foreign keys option was added to the string (not sure), the connection errors out.

Comment: You want turn on fk?

Comment: I thought all I needed to do to turn on foreign keys was as shown.  Obviously in tables I'm setting up those relationships.  Is there something else I need to do to allow the use of foreign keys?

Answer (score 0):

Foreign key constraints are disabled by default (for backwards compatibility), so must be enabled separately for each database connection.The application can also use a PRAGMA foreign_keys statement to determine if foreign keys are currently enabled. The following command-line session demonstrates this:

> sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;

```
  SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + sFileName + "; Version=3;", true);
    connection.Open();
    SQLiteCommand mycommand = new SQLiteCommand(connection);
    mycommand.CommandText = "PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON";
    mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
   connection.Close();
```

Comment: I've read in several posts that this can be accomplished in the connection string, similar to what I have shown.  Is turning on foreign keys in the connection string possible?